# XML end tag getting changed on message queue

Tags: xml

I have an embedded tag in an xml doc that I do not want processed on my queue.
I am sending string:

```
<aTag>
&lt;Some Text&gt;
</aTag>
```

This is a text message i am putting on a queue.
The less than is coming through as it should, but the queue is converting the greater than to ">".

What can I send instead?

Comment: Without more details on how all this is happening (what queue? how is it being processed? what languages are involved?) nobody can help you.

Comment: language doesn't matter, its xml. i'm looking for other options to get ">" passed through, since "&gt;" is not working (which people use for such a case), what other options are there?

Comment: Without knowing what bits of software are involved we can't possibly point you in the right direction. There is no single answer to "how do I push data through an unidentified black box and get it to come out a specific way?", which is all you've provided so far.

Comment: i'll have to see if i can refine the question

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing a problem here. Here is what the XML standard [says](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#syntax):

> The ampersand character (&) and the left angle bracket (<) MUST NOT appear in their literal form, except when used as markup delimiters, or within a comment, a processing instruction, or a CDATA section. If they are needed elsewhere, they MUST be escaped using either numeric character references or the strings " `&amp;` " and " `&lt;` " respectively. **The right angle bracket (>) *may* be represented using the string " `&gt;` "**, and MUST, for compatibility, be escaped using either " `&gt;` " or a character reference when it appears in the string " ]]> " in content, when that string is not marking the end of a CDATA section.

(Emphasis added.)

In the context in which your `&gt;` appears, `>` is equivalent.